# Convert php regex to java one

Tags: java, php, regex

I need to convert next php regex:

```
/^ (?: \d{1,16} | (?: \x0A | \x0D | [\x20-\x5A] | \x5F | [\x61-\x7A] | \xC2\xA0 | \xCE\xA9 ){1,11} ) $/xsi
```

I'm new with regex and I found a useful link:
http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Do I understand correct, that there I should only paste php regex, press "Test" and this result:

```
'/^ (?: \\d{1,16} | (?: \\x0A | \\x0D | [\\x20-\\x5A] | \\x5F | [\\x61-\\x7A] | \\xC2\\xA0 | \\xCE\\xA9 ){1,11} ) $/xsi'
```

would be working in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original pattern looks strange: most of the characters written with `\x..` are in the ASCII table. Why using this complex notation when you can write (for example) `\n` for `\x0A`, `\r` for `\x0D` etc.? It can be written in a more simple way (always for PHP):

```
/^(?:\d{1,16}|(?:\n|\r|[ -Z]|_|[a-z]|\xC2\xA0|\xCE\xA9){1,11})$/i
```

*(I removed the x modifier and non-significant spaces. The s modifier was useless.)*

Since the pattern is case-insensitive (modifier i), `[a-z]` is already included in `[ -Z]` (that contains `[A-Z]`, see the ASCII table) and can be removed. Other thing, using a character class instead of an alternation of single characters is shorter and more performant:

```
/^(?:\d{1,16}|(?:[\n\r -Z_]|\xC2\xA0|\xCE\xA9){1,11})$/i
```

About `\xC2\xA0` and `\xCE\xA9`: These sequences stand for the characters `NO-BREAK SPACE` and `GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA` encoded in UTF8.

PCRE (the PHP regex engine) doesn't support unicode by default and read a string as a sequence of single bytes (one byte per character). It is possible to read strings as UTF8 encoded strings if you add the `u` modifier or if you starts the pattern with `(*UTF8)`. In your pattern, there is no `u` modifier so each byte is seen as a character.

The Java regex engine supports unicode by default and doesn't read a string byte by byte but character by character.

To make the "translation" from PHP to Java easier, I will rewrite the PHP pattern with the u modifier:

```
/^(?:[0-9]{1,16}|[\n\r -Z_\x{00A0}\x{03A9}]{1,11})$/iu
```

`\xC2\xA0` which describes each byte is now replaced with `\x{00A0}` where `00A0` is the unicode code point for the character `NO-BREAK SPACE`. Same thing for omega. *(take a look at [the unicode table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/))*

Note that the u modifier extends `\d` to all digits in the unicode table. To prevent this side effect, I have replaced it with `[0-9]`.

To write the Java pattern, all you need is to replace the `\x{....}` syntax with the `\u....` syntax and to use the CASE_INSENSITIVE option:

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,16}|[\n\r -Z_\u00A0\u03A9]{1,11})$
```

*(don't forget to escape the backslashes)*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm new to regexps and original regex is not mine, so I cannot say anything about its strange. I just need to convert it into Java. Thanks again!